# No access token delivered to webhook after normal account linking

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

- Conversation Flow : android device/web simulator - google assistant - api.ai - webhook - [websocket/FCM push] - android device

From end of last week, access token is not delivered to our webhook server even if account linking was successful and it is displayed on web simulator debugging window. When we logged on webhook server, the account token value from api.ai was NULL. After this happened, next account linking is not processed even if I reset (turn it off and on again) api.ai agent.
I tried to make new actions project and migrate api.ai agent to new one, but it was the same. I make sure the same test has been successful before last week.

If anyone has gone through the similar issue, I hope your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was also very confused because I was expecting the accessToken to be in the same JSON format as shown in the simulator.

if still not working please send the body of the request you receive not what the simulator show you.

but it's under originalRequest.data.user.accessToken.
if you are using NodeJS you don't need to parse anything you will just need to call :
getUser().accessToken
from ApiAiApp object in the actions-on-google node library.